# How do you convert the remainder of a division operation to a fixed point in C?

Tags: c, fixed-point

I understand the concept of fixed point pretty well at this point, but I'm having trouble making a logical jump.

I'm working with M68000 CPUs using gcc with no standard libraries of any sort. Using DIVU/DIVS opcodes, I can obtain the quotient and the remainder. Given a Q16.16 fixed point value stored in an unsigned 32bit memory space, I know I can put the quotient in the upper 16 bits. However, how does one convert the integer remainder into the fractional portion of the fixed point value?

I'm sure this is something simple and I'm just missing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without worrying about overflow, just truncating any result over 16 bits, you can take the 16 low bits of one value, and combine with the low 16 bits of the other result, and combine it into a single 32 bit value representing your fixed-point value.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the other result? It's only one operation. So, as the example I've been working with, 177 / 120 = 1.475, or when using DIVU, 1 with a remainder of 57. It's getting that 57 to represent 0.475 in the lower 16 bits that I'm stuck on.

Edit: actually I think I was able to figure out what you meant by other operation, which is converting the remainder to a fractional value. In the example I gave, 57 / 120. And then multiply that by 65536 as the lower 16 bits. Thank you for the hint that!

Comment: If the dividend (numerator) and divisor (denominator) are both 16 bit integers, you could multiply the dividend by 65536 (or shift left 16 bits) and divide by the divisor. E.g. 177 * 65536 / 120 = 96665 remainder 72. If you ignore the remainder, 96665 represents the Q16.16 value 1.47499 (approximately). It gets trickier if dividing fractions.

Comment: `using gcc` do you have `_Fract` `_Acc` `stdfix.h`? `16.16` should be `unsigned _Accum`

Comment: If the dividend and divisor are Q16.16 values then in standard C you could cast the dividend (numerator) to `int_least64_t` (for signed division) or to `uint_least64_t` (for unsigned division), multiply by 65536 and divide by the divisor. The resulting Q16.16 quotient is in the bottom 32 bits (but arithmetic overflow into the upper 32 bits could have occurred).

Comment: @Ryou The answer you posted (and then deleted) looked fine to me.  Did it not work for you?  Was there some additional complication you wanted help with?

Answer (score 1):

The way to think about it is that fixed point numbers are actually integers hold the value of your number times some fixed multiplier.  You want to build you fixed point operations out of the integer operations you have available in your hardware.

So for a 16.16 fixed-point format, your multiplier is 65536 (2<sup>16</sup>), so if you want to do a divide c = a/b, the numbers (integers) you have to work with are actually a' = a * 65536 and b' = b * 65536 and you want to find c' = c * 65536.  So substituting into the desired c = a/b, you have

c'/65536 = (a'/65536) / (b'/65536) = a'/b'
c' = 65536 * a' / b'

So you actually want to first (integer) mulitply the fixed-point value of a by 65536 (left shift by 16), then do an integer divide by the fixed point value of b, and that will give you the fixed point value of c.  The issue is that the first multiply will almost certainly overflow 32 bits, so you need a 64 bit (actually only 48 bit) intermediate.  So if you're using a 68020+ with a 64/32  DIVS.L instruction (divides a 64 bit value in a pair of registers by a 32 bit value), you're fine.  You don't need the remainder at all.

If you're using a pure 68000 that doesn't have the wide divide, you'll need to do 16-bit long division on the values (where you use 16 bit numbers as "digits", so you're dividing a 3-"digit" number by a 2-"digit" one)